# How do I make target ALWAYS open a new window HTML

Tags: html

What I am doing is sending a user a link to a page but I want to close that page once the user submits the form.

To do this I have to open a new window for the user

```
//this always opens a new tab not a new window
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">open in new window</a>
```

after the user opens the link I don't want to close his/her browser (from where the user opened the link). All i am sending is the link in a e-mail.

Comment: So (1) you want to open a new window AND (2) you want to close it later AND (3) you have code that DOES open it in a new window (which makes *1* redundant) but (4) you DON'T want to close the window (which contradicts *2*). I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: You've answered your title question yourself already. I'm very confused by your wording what your issue is in your main question however. What exactly is not working?

Comment: After your edit, the question still isn't clear. Are you trying to ask "*How can make a link, in an HTML formatted email, open in a new browser window instead of a new tab in an existing browser window?*"

Comment: No. The user gets the link from his email. (I already have that). What I want is that when the user presses on the link, the link opens in a new window (not a tab of the window where the user is currently in on his or her email account) @Quentin

Comment: @learningbyexample — How is that different from what I said?

Comment: @Quentin sorry didn't read it right. That is the question

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you have any control over.

Given a target attribute indicating that a new browsing context should be opened, the choice between opening a new tab or a new window is a user preference and not under the control of the page author.

If you were using JavaScript, then you could specify the dimensions of the window using `window.open()` and a side effect of that would be to trigger a new window instead of a new tab. Since you are working in an email, that isn't an option. Email clients strip JavaScript from HTML formatted emails.

Comment: that is what I want to have control over.

Comment: @learningbyexample — You might want that, but you don't and can't have it.